# Display collections of objects in DataGridViews

Tags: c#, .net

Using an ORM approach in applications can often lead to the scenario where you have a collection of objects you've retrieved and would like to display them in a tabular view using a DataGridView.

In my (limited) experience, binding collections of objects using a custom BindingList to a DataGridView results in poor performance and unsatisfactory sorting.  I'm looking for a generic solution to this problem such that it's straightforward to populate a DataGridView and also extract the underlying objects later.

I will describe a good solution I've found, but I'm looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to preface this answer with the statement that my experience is within the 2.0 Framework domain.  The newer Frameworks may offer other solutions.

Below is a BindingList derived class that supports bi-directional sorting and other useful features of List.  I can't take credit for the PropertyComparer sorting.  I found this in an article a while back, but now I see it is all over the Internet so I unfortunately cannot cite the original source.

Another alternative is the BindingListView:  [http://blw.sourceforge.net](http://blw.sourceforge.net/).  This class allows you to create a view of a List collection, like you would with a DataTable object, including the ability to define a Filter and a Sort.

```
public class UsefulBindingList<T> : BindingList<T>
{
    private bool _isSorted = false;
    private ListSortDirection _sortDirection;
    private PropertyDescriptor _sortProperty;

    protected override bool SupportsSortingCore
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    protected override bool IsSortedCore
    {
        get { return _isSorted; }
    }

    protected override ListSortDirection SortDirectionCore
    {
        get { return _sortDirection; }
    }

    protected override PropertyDescriptor SortPropertyCore
    {
        get { return _sortProperty; }
    }


    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        IEnumerator<T> e = collection.GetEnumerator();
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            this.Add(e.Current);
        }
    }

    public T Find(Predicate<T> match)
    {
        List<T> items = this.Items as List<T>;
        if (items != null)
            return items.Find(match);
        else
            return default(T);
    }

    public int FindIndex(Predicate<T> match)
    {
        List<T> items = this.Items as List<T>;
        if (items != null)
            return items.FindIndex(match);
        else
            return -1;
    }

    public bool Exists(Predicate<T> match)
    {
        List<T> items = this.Items as List<T>;
        return items.Exists(match);
    }

    public void Sort()
    {
        List<T> items = this.Items as List<T>;
        if (items != null)
            items.Sort();
    }

    public void Sort(Comparison<T> comparison)
    {
        List<T> items = this.Items as List<T>;
        if (items != null)
            items.Sort(comparison);
    }

    public void Sort(IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        List<T> items = this.Items as List<T>;
        if (items != null)
            items.Sort(comparer);
    }

    protected override void ApplySortCore(PropertyDescriptor prop, ListSortDirection direction)
    {
        _sortProperty = prop;
        _sortDirection = direction;

        List<T> items = this.Items as List<T>;
        if (items != null)
        {
            PropertyComparer<T> pc = new PropertyComparer<T>(prop, direction);
            items.Sort(pc);
            _isSorted = true;
        }
        else
        {
            _isSorted = false;
        }
        this.OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1));
    }

    protected override void RemoveSortCore()
    {
        _isSorted = false;
    }

}

public class PropertyComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    private ListSortDirection _sortDirection;
    private PropertyDescriptor _property;

    public PropertyComparer(PropertyDescriptor property, ListSortDirection direction)
    {
        _property = property;
        _sortDirection = direction;
    }

    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        int rv = 0;
        object vx = _property.GetValue(x);
        object vy = _property.GetValue(y);
        rv = System.Collections.Comparer.Default.Compare(vx, vy);
        if (_sortDirection == ListSortDirection.Descending)
            rv = -rv;
        return rv;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Javier Lozano proposes converting a collection of objects to a DataTable and then convert the DataRows back to objects as necessary. His solution uses reflection to make it generic.  He's even posted the [code on his blog](http://blog.lozanotek.com/archive/2007/05/09/Converting_Custom_Collections_To_and_From_DataTable.aspx).  I made some minor modifications to support Nullable types in the object, and this seems to be working well for me so far.